# avoid multi updates to database PHP&MYSQLI

Tags: php, mysqli, memcached

I have a site , on my site every time that someone is clicking on a banner i am doing a select query to take all the relevant links so today i have about 1000000 clicks a day on links , this process is making too many querys on the server 
what other options do i have ?

i was thinking about using

```
memcache
```

and than to ask the server cache for the hosted link and every 5 minutes

i will run a

```
CronJob
```

that will give me the link.

there is any other kind of technologies i can use ?

memcache is a safe technology to use ?

Comment: just try to explain what is your problem? what is your current situation/result? what is your expected/desired result?

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure this is a large open-ended topic that doesn't have one particular answer. But if you are asking if people use `memcache` to take the load off the database server?

> Certainly yes. `memcached` is more than a decade old now; been
>   tested and used by a lot many more companies.

You could figure out the most frequent queries that your database server is getting and then start by caching the result set into `memcache` (and update your memcached whenever database inserts, updates & deletions occur).

You'd also observe that `memcached` is also frequently compared to `redis`.

There are several techniques that you can use to take off the load on your database. Please check out the answers here[1]

[1] https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/60225/how-do-you-off-load-work-from-the-database